# controller_path(object) is returning website.com/controller.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, link-to

I have manually created a new View for an existing scaffolded Model in my Rails app because, well I thought that was the point, I can create multiple views for the same Model.  Everything seems to function fine except that when I try to link_to an item in the view then Rails gives me the wrong URL.

- routes.rb has the proper "resources :controller"
- controller_controller.rb exists and works fine
- views/controller/show.html.erb exists and works fine
- link_to "controller", controller_path #works fine

link_to "controller", controller_path(object) # links to controller but adds the id as ".id" instead of "/id"

Any ideas why?

**rake routes output**

```
pups     GET /pups(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"pups"} 
         POST /pups(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"pups"} 
new_pup  GET /pups/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"pups"} 
edit_pup GET /pups/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"pups"}
pup      GET /pups/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pups"} 
         PUT /pups/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"pups"} 
         DELETE /pups/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"pups"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your link_to is using `pup_path(object)` and not `pups_path(object)` (plural).

Comment: I'm not actually using controller but since you think the name may be important, I'm using "Pups"  I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Ah, ok. Always a good idea to post the exact code you're using. Can you post the relevant portion of `rake routes`?

Comment: pups GET /pups(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"pups"}
POST /pups(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"pups"}
new_pup GET /pups/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"pups"}
edit_pup GET /pups/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"pups"}pup GET    /pups/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pups"}
PUT    /pups/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"pups"}
DELETE /pups/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"pups"}

Comment: Gah!  The formatting didn't work there.  I tried to make it readable.  Do you comments loose formating here?

Comment: Added the routes to your original post, and revised my answer. See above.